# Junk host name while using nslookup, How to change it?

Tags: linux, redhat, hostname

My question is regarding the host name mapped to a machine's IP. I am new to Linux, I have a machine to test whether our j2ee based web application runs fine in linux box. we are able to deploy our application and successfully and even able to access the same in that machine. But when I tried accessing it through another machine in the same network, I am not able to access the URL using the hostname specified, instead I am able to access if I provide the ipaddress.

I tried putting nslookup MyIP# command to know the name of the ip in the DNS server, where I got some junk *value*.com; when I tried to access with that name I am able to access the machine.

Kindly provide me inputs to change the hostname of this machine in that domain server.

Thanks in Advance!!

Jay

Comment: I believe this question might be more suitable for http://superuser.com/ since it's not a programming question.

Comment: you question is too vague your not giving us anything to help you out.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give more details about the dns server, it's configuration, etc..

Answer (score 0):

The problem will lie with your DNS server having old/outdated DNS entries - try checking them on the DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to setup a hostname A record in your own Domain you control, either on your name server or through your domain registrar that points at the IP address of the server.

Or on the machine you are testing from you can add a record to the local hosts file.  I assume you are using Windows, so here is more info about the hosts file http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

If you want to change the reverse lookup that you got by doing "nslookup IP" you need to contact the owner of the IP address, typically the ISP.  You can find out who owns it by checking the whois registry http://www.ip-address.org/tracer/ip-whois.php